# In WP7, how to Add Tile form My ListBox Item?

Tags: windows-phone-7, tiles

I try to add Tile form ListBox Item of my app:
Like Friend hub, Game hub...
Let User tap one item, show "pin to start",
then more Tiles on start page with different picture or word.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to add more than one tile for your application to the home page in the same way that you can with map locations from the Map app and with notes from the OneNote application? If so, then you can't do this with the current development framework, though I personally hope that it will be available in the future.

Comment: Just adding that with the 7.1 SDK (Mango) This is now possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean adding to the phone home screen, there can only be one tile for your app. This is added via the application list to the right of the home screen via tap and hold on your app icon.

Comment: no, 
like Friend Hub, Games Hub, Office Hub, 
you can tap one item to "pin to start", 
then more tile will show on home screen of one App.

Comment: Understood, but you can't do this with 3rd party apps at present. It might be nice if the facility is added though, feel free to suggest it on their forums.